# MySQLi and PHP sends only single products on the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, insertion

I can't find where is the problem at my code. It only send single orders to the database. When I order in my cart 2 or more than items, it only sends the last order. I don't have any idea how I can change or add some syntax in my code.

Here is my code in checkout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo '<h3>Your Order</h3>';
$current_url = base64_encode($url='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  if(isset($_SESSION['products'])){
     echo '<ol>';
     echo '<form action="checkout_with_us.php" method="POST">';
     $total = 0;
     $cart_items = 0;

        foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $cart_itm){
           $product_code = $cart_itm['code'];
           $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_name,product_desc,price FROM products WHERE product_code='$product_code' LIMIT 1");
             $obj = $results->fetch_object();
                echo '<li>';
                echo 'Price: '.$currency.$obj->price;
                echo '<h4>'.$obj->product_name.'(Code: '.$product_code.')</h4>';
                echo 'Qty: '.$cart_itm['qty'];
                echo '</li>';

                   $subtotal = ($cart_itm['price'] * $cart_itm['qty']);
                     $total = ($total + $subtotal);
                     $cart_items++;
                       echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'.$obj->product_name.'">';
                       echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_desc" value="'.$obj->product_desc.'">';
                       echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_qty" value="'.$cart_itm["qty"].'">';
                       echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_code" value="'.$product_code.'">';     
                }
                    echo '<strong>Sub Total: '.$currency.$total.'</strong>';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="price" value="'.$total.'">';
                    echo '</ol>';   
                    }

//Here is the information of the customer
echo 'Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br />';
echo 'Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br />';
echo 'Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br />';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Send Step">';

echo '</form>';
?>
```

And here is my checkout.with_us.php codes. This code is the bridge to send the information to the database.

```
<?php
session_start();
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$order_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$order_code = $_POST['item_code'];
$order_qty = $_POST['item_qty'];
$sub_total = $_POST['price'];

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','sampsix')or die('Could not connect');

$query = "INSERT INTO `sampsix`.`orders`(`firstname`,`lastname`,`email`,`OrderName`,`OrderCode`,`OrderQty`,`SubTotal`) VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$order_name','$order_code','$order_qty','$sub_total')";

mysqli_query($conn,$query);

mysqli_close($conn);

header('Location: checkout.php');
?>
```

Comment: You posted this already http://stackoverflow.com/q/25821058/

Comment: Yes sir. Still I have no answer to help me :(

Comment: if you want to have several values in one `$_POST['xxx']` you need to set it up as an array: `$_POST['xxx'][]`

Comment: What do you mean sir @Razah? :)

Comment: Mr. S. Pols just answered your question. Thats what i meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete your other question, ok?

The problem is you loop through `$_SESSION` and use the same `name` value each time. You need to create an array of your inputs. Here is an example:

```
<?php
echo '<h3>Your Order</h3>';
$current_url = base64_encode($url='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  if(isset($_SESSION['products'])){
     echo '<ol>';
     echo '<form action="checkout_with_us.php" method="POST">';
     $total = 0;
     $cart_items = 0;

        foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $cart_itm){
           $product_code = $cart_itm['code'];
           $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_name,product_desc,price FROM products WHERE product_code='$product_code' LIMIT 1");
             $obj = $results->fetch_object();
                echo '<li>';
                echo 'Price: '.$currency.$obj->price;
                echo '<h4>'.$obj->product_name.'(Code: '.$product_code.')</h4>';
                echo 'Qty: '.$cart_itm['qty'];
                echo '</li>';

                   $subtotal = ($cart_itm['price'] * $cart_itm['qty']);
                     $total = ($total + $subtotal);
                     $cart_items++;
                       echo '<input type="hidden" name="product['.$product_code.'][item_name]" value="'.$obj->product_name.'">';
                       echo '<input type="hidden" name="product['.$product_code.'][item_desc]" value="'.$obj->product_desc.'">';
                       echo '<input type="hidden" name="product['.$product_code.'][item_qty]" value="'.$cart_itm["qty"].'">';
                       echo '<input type="hidden" name="product['.$product_code.'][item_code]" value="'.$product_code.'">';     
                }
                    echo '<strong>Sub Total: '.$currency.$total.'</strong>';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="product['.$product_code.'][price]" value="'.$total.'">';
                    echo '</ol>';   
                    }

//Here is the information of the customer
echo 'Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br />';
echo 'Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br />';
echo 'Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br />';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Send Step">';

echo '</form>';
?>
```

You can catch this by looping in your `product` array:

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','sampsix')or die('Could not connect');

foreach($_POST['product'] as $product)
{
    $order_name = $product['item_name'];
    $order_code = $product['item_code'];
    $order_qty = $product['item_qty'];
    $sub_total = $product['price'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `sampsix`.`orders`(`firstname`,`lastname`,`email`,`OrderName`,`OrderCode`,`OrderQty`,`SubTotal`) VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$order_name','$order_code','$order_qty','$sub_total')";
    mysqli_query($conn,$query);
}



mysqli_close($conn);

header('Location: checkout.php');
?>
```

I don't know what the purpose is of the table `orders` but with my example the products will be added to this table with the same `firstname`, `lastname`, etc.

Comment: Hahaha Thank God! It is done sir! you're a awesome teacher. The multiple orders has been sent and the last order holds the "Sub Total" How did you do that? :D

Comment: Finally hehe. Your main problem was you where using the same `name` value each `input`. Because they all have the same name, only the last value gets passed. When you use the `[]` brackets you create an array of information, where you can store multiple rows.

Comment: Aha! Yeah I see my mistake. haha just the name. There is no array in each object that I want to send. Ahahaha Thank you for that wonderful explanation. Can I still ask one question. Because I'm confused. After I send the order to my "order.php", how can I view the table information of multiple order with the same name. My code in "order.php" is only can view the single order. Can you see my code if you have a time? :)

Comment: Sure, just post it into your question and if your current question is answered, please close by marking it as accepted.

Comment: Yes sir. haha anyway sir. where do I find the "Accepted button" so sorry sir. I'm a newbie here at stackoverflow. :)